# How can I parallelize fitting a gradient boosting model with sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Relatively new to model building with sklearn. I know cross validation can be parallelized via the n_jobs parameter, but if I'm not using CV, how can I utilize my available cores to speed up model fitting?

Comment: There is no parameter for that, meaning you can't do much. I'm not familiar with the internals of gradient-boosting, but make sure that you got a nice numpy-setup including some multithreaded BLAS. If gradient-boosting is based on vector-vector/matrix-vector products (which i would expect, at least for calculating gradients), these operations will be automatically parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives like XGboost or LigtGMB that are distributed (i.e., can run parallel). These are well documented and popular boosting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment afaik there is no parameter like "n_jobs" for the GradientBoosting method, but you can try to use the [HistGradientBoostingRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor) which uses OpenMP for parallelization (will use as many threads as possible).

You can read more here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#parallelism